# How to print single and double quotes in the same string?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-interface, frontend

I'm working on a project where we use both asp and Javascript to create the front end of it. We have a table where users input strings that can have both single and double quotes at times. My code handles only one of the quotes at a time. How do I make my code handle both of it at the same time?

```
<td <%=cl%> style="width:<%=colwid(c)-4%>;text-align:<%=align(c)%>;" **origvalue="<%=cell%>"**><%=cell%></td>
```

original value holds the string.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a string contain the same type of quotes you used to delimit the string, you have to *escape* the quote characters. In other words, you have to put a `\` character before the quote character you want to use in your string.

For example:

``` console.log('\'Hello world!\''); // prints 'Hello world!'
console.log("\"Hello world!\""); // prints "Hello world!"
console.log(`\`Hello world!\``); // prints `Hello world!` ```

You only need to escape the quote characters which match the string's delimiters, but you can escape any of the quote characters in any type of JS string.